# In Memory CSV download file name

Tags: python, django

I am using csv writer to create a csv in memory and returning it as a response using django.

My code looks like this.

```
response = HttpResponse (content_type='text/csv')
writer = csv.writer(response)
writer.writerow(['rizwan','mumtaz'])
......
return response
```

The code is working fine, but every time I get `'download.csv'` how can I change the name `'download.csv'` to `somethigelse.csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/outputting-csv/